# Mysql Cluster replication issue on create table by select command

Tags: mysql-cluster

I have problem on slave replication on mysql cluster.

When I create table with select as `CREATE TABLE tmp1 AS SELCT * FROM tmp2`
the table can be created but the sql is not recorded in binlog and not replicated to slave.

But if I create table by definition or like as: `CREATE TABLE tmp1 LIKE tmp2" OR "CREATE TABLE`tmp1`(`id`int(11) NOT NULL )`, the sql commands can be recorded in `binlog` and will be replicated to slave.

Is there any setting on this?

My mysql cluster version is 5.6.31-ndb-7.4.12-cluster-gpl-log and my default engine is ndbcluster.

Comment: This is probably what you are running into http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/replication-features-create-select.html

Answer (score 0):

If you want to replicate your Table you have to add ENGINE=ndbcluster
Like this : `CREATE TABLE tmp1 AS SELCT * FROM tmp2 ENGINE=ndbcluster;`

For existing tables you can use : `ALTER TABLE tbl_name ENGINE=NDBCLUSTER;`

More infos here : https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysql-cluster-install-example-data.html

Good luck !